# How to deserialize the given xml with Restsharp?

Tags: c#, xml, rest, deserialization, restsharp

I would like to ask a question to understand how to deserialize an xml to object comes from an api.

```
<Sistemrent>
<Sube id="1">
    <Sube_Kodu>ABC</Sube_Kodu>
    <Sube_Ismi>AAA BBB</Sube_Ismi>
    <Kayit_ID>1</Kayit_ID>
</Sube>
<Sube id="2">
    <Sube_Kodu>BCD</Sube_Kodu>
    <Sube_Ismi>BBB CCC</Sube_Ismi>
    <Kayit_ID>1</Kayit_ID>
</Sube>
</Sistemrent>
```

You can find the following class that we generate for parsing of that xml.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sistemrent")]
public class Sistemrent
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sube")]
    public List<Sube> Sube { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sube")]
public class Sube
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sube_Kodu")]
    public string Sube_Kodu { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sube_Ismi")]
    public string Sube_Ismi { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Kayit_ID")]
    public string Kayit_ID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

It does not convert the xml to object and need your helps.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using, our crystal balls are on collective strike this week, we will have to use manual data transmission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace Oppgave3Lesson1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Sistemrent));

            Sistemrent sistemrent = (Sistemrent)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sistemrent")]
    public class Sistemrent
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sube")]
        public List<Sube> Sube { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sube")]
    public class Sube
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sube_Kodu")]
        public string Sube_Kodu { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sube_Ismi")]
        public string Sube_Ismi { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Kayit_ID")]
        public string Kayit_ID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting a string instead of a FILENAME?  Then use this : StringReader strReader = new StringReader(response);  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strReader);